# Which approach to storing items in a linked-list is faster?

Tags: algorithm, linked-list, divide-and-conquer

There's a question in my algorithm textbook for practice that I'm not sure of, and was hoping someone can elaborate / explain:

When you design a divide and conquer algorithm to store items in a linked list of size n, would dividing the problem in half be asymptotically faster in the worst case scenario than the algorithm dividing the list into a single subproblem of size 1 and another of size n-1?

Comment: **Storing** items in a linked list or **sorting** items in a linked list?

Comment: Storing items in linked list

Answer (score 1):

regard the process as a tree structure, like:

```
          [1,          n]
         /               \
 [1,     n/2]             [n/2,       n]
 /           \             /            \
[1, n/4] [n/4, n/2]  [n/2, n*3/4] [n*3/4, n]
```

the time cost depends on how much calculation you do on each level.

e.g. find the maximum number in an array.

```
int f1(int a[], int n){
    if (n == 1) return a[0];
    return max(a[0], f1(a + 1, n - 1));
}


int f2(int a[], int n){
    if (n == 1) return a[0];
    return max(f2(a, n / 2), f2(a + n / 2, n - n / 2));
}
```

the calculation you do on each level is `O(1)`, so both `f1` and `f2` is `O(n)` in total.

or as you mentioned, the `quicksort` algorithm, the calculation you do on each level is `O(n)`, so the total cost depends on how many levels there are.

if we divide it into `[1, n/2]` and `[n/2, n]`, there would be `O(logn)` levels and total time cost is `O(nlogn)`.

and if we divide it into `[1, 1]` and `[2, n]`, there would be `O(n)` levels, so the total time cost would be `O(n^2)`